# sp_addsrvrolemember not granting login

Tags: sql, sql-server

According to MSDN documentation this proc is supposed to grant login to a windows user, but when i run the following script, I cannot login using the specified user even though the account shows up under security.

```
exec sp_addsrvrolemember 'domain\user','dbcreator'
```

also is there a way to query if a particular login can actually login to the server or not ?

I should add that i know one should create login using CREATE LOGIN statement, just wondering if sp_addsrvrrole is behaving as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN says to use [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751(SQL.90).aspx) (which replaces [sp_grantlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173449(SQL.90).aspx) and [sp_addlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768(SQL.90).aspx)) which says

> Creates a new SQL Server login.

Once you have created the login, then you run [sp_addsrvrolemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186320(SQL.90).aspx) which says:

> Adds a login as a member of a fixed server role.

This means the login should already exist before you run sp_addsrvrolemember

To test if a login exists at the SQL Server level, use [SUSER_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176042(SQL.90).aspx) which will give the internal key from [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786(SQL.90).aspx)

```
SELECT SUSER_ID('DOMAIN\User')
```

Edit:

Some system stored procs will create a sys.server_principals entry but it's not usable

You need to run this now. Or DROP LOGIN first and recreate as above

```
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO <login>
```

Comment: but sp_addsrvrolemember succeeds even without creating a login, and creates a login. The SUSER_ID function returns a value, but the user is not able to login. Shouldn't it fail if the login is not there ?